# Global Variables and Functions

Tags: php, function, global

if I have a function that needs to use $foo,

And `global $foo` is so frowned upon,

how can i get my function to access the variable without it being global?  Is there another way or method to do this that I am not aware of?

Comment: Why not pass it as an argument?

Comment: The imperative coders will surely disagree, but if `global $foo` is frowned upon depends on the actual variable name and usage. If you're using such a shallow variable name, and maybe a dozen others, then you are polluting the shared scope, and possibly open the door to inadvertent overwriting or misuse it for signaling.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this..

```
<?php
    $name = "batman";

    function get_details($name,$age){
        $temp_str = "Name: ".$name."<br />Age: ".$age;
        return($temp_str);
    }

    echo get_details($name,35); // passing through name as a variable and the age as just text...
?>
```

Gives...

```
Name: batman
Age: 35
```